# Mongodb use array as unique key

Tags: mongodb

I want to make sure I only have one instance a documents that is an agreement between to entities... I may have modeled this wrong, so Im looking for suggestions if there is a better way to do this.

but in essence, the document looks like this.

```
{
    _id:objectid,
    entity_Ids: [objectid]
}
```

I was curious what's the best way to make sure the array is unique so id I do
db.agreements.insert(entity_Ids:[1,2]) and there is already a 1,2 I'll get a conflict.

I could have done it like this :

```
{
    _id:objectid,
    entity1: objectid,
    entity2: objectid
}
```

but then I'd always have to do a check of where entit1=1 or entity2=1 or entity1=2 or entity2=2

Answer (score 0):

you can create unique index on any key in the document
so in your case try

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({entity_Ids: 1},{unique: true});
```